# PHP Semaphore compatible with CPP application in Ubuntu

Tags: php, c++, mutex, shared-memory, semaphore

I have a PHP code that has a shared memory with a CPP app, the PHP is the producer and the CPP is the consumer.
I had the things working on but I discover that sometimes the code messes up and don't work properly, as I researched a little I found that PHP semaphores are in fact a 3 semaphores object so that might be the problem here.
I need a way to have a mutex between both codes and avoid these kind of issues.

Here is an example of my PHP code:

```
if (!$sem_id = sem_get($sem_key)) {
    echo "Could not get ID for the semaphore.\n";
} else {
    if (!sem_acquire($sem_id)) {
        echo "failed.\n";
    } else {
        //echo "Sem ID: " . $sem_id . "<br/>";
        if ($shm = shmop_open($shm_key, "c", 0666, 1048576)) {

            $count = unpack('L', shmop_read($shm, 0, 4));
            $count = reset($count);

            $count++;
            shmop_write($shm, pack('L', $count), 0);
            shmop_write($shm, pack('L', $section_id) . $data, 4 + ($count-1) * 30);

        } else {
            echo "Couldnt't open shmop.";
        }
        sem_release($sem_id);
    }
}
```

And for the CPP app I use this functions I found:

```
static int semaphore1_get_access(void)
{
    struct sembuf sem_b;
    sem_b.sem_num = 0;
    sem_b.sem_op = -1; /* P() */
    sem_b.sem_flg = SEM_UNDO;
    if (semop(semaphore1_id, &sem_b, 1) == -1)      //Wait until free
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "semaphore1_get_access failed\n");
        return(0);
    }
    return(1);
}

static int semaphore1_release_access(void)
{
    struct sembuf sem_b;
    sem_b.sem_num = 0;
    sem_b.sem_op = 1; /* V() */
    sem_b.sem_flg = SEM_UNDO;
    if (semop(semaphore1_id, &sem_b, 1) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "semaphore1_release_access failed\n");
        return(0);
    }
    return(1);
}
```

As I said I think that the issue here is the way that PHP handles Semaphores, if someone knows how to adapt that functions to be compatibles with the PHP ones I would really appreciate it.

Thank you all for your help!.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after trying a lot of things.
This way seems to have fixed the issue:

```
static int semaphore1_get_access(int num)
{

    struct sembuf sops[3]; //struct sembuf *sops = (struct sembuf *) malloc(3*sizeof(struct sembuf));

    sops[0].sem_num = 0;
    sops[0].sem_op = -1; /* P() */
    sops[0].sem_flg = SEM_UNDO;
    sops[1].sem_num = 1;
    sops[1].sem_op = 1; /* P() */
    sops[1].sem_flg = SEM_UNDO;


    if (semop(semaphore1_id, sops, 2) == -1)        //Wait until free
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "semaphore1_get_access failed\n");
        return(0);
    }

    return(1);

}

static int semaphore1_release_access(int num)
{
    struct sembuf sops[3];// = (struct sembuf *) malloc(3*sizeof(struct sembuf));

    sops[0].sem_num = 0;
    sops[0].sem_op = 1; /* P() */
    sops[0].sem_flg = SEM_UNDO;
    sops[1].sem_num = 1;
    sops[1].sem_op = -1; /* P() */
    sops[1].sem_flg = SEM_UNDO;

    if (semop(semaphore1_id, sops, 2) == -1)        //Wait until free
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "semaphore1_get_access failed\n");
        return(0);
    }



return(1);
}
```

I'm not doing use of the third semaphore but I don't know if that may have consecuenses.

I found this information about the way that PHP handles semaphores:
http://www.serverphorums.com/read.php?8,313695

What I found usefull was that
The first semaphore from the set of 3 is the real one, blocking the process or not,
The second one is use to know how many processes are accesing the semaphore
And the third is use to control the access to the second semaphore.